# Implement Socket Programming in Android

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io

Socket.io gives an error **SocketIOException: Error while handshaking**, 
How do i solved it. and in my gradle file. I wan to developed an app which works only on socket connectvity.

**If is ther any other library exists please refer me that which i can easily integrate in my application.**

=>Gradle

```
compile ('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.9.0') {
    // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

=>Main Activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;


import netsol.app.socketioexample.SocketUtils.IOAcknowledge;
import netsol.app.socketioexample.SocketUtils.IOCallback;
import netsol.app.socketioexample.SocketUtils.SocketIO;
import netsol.app.socketioexample.SocketUtils.SocketIOException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        socketStart();
    }

    SocketIO socket = null;
    private void socketStart() {

        try {
            socket = new SocketIO("http://xxx.xxx.x.23:808");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                System.out.println("an Error occured");
                socketIOException.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection established");
            }

            @Override
            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
            }


        });

        // This line is cached until the connection is establisched.
        socket.send("Hello Server!");
    }

    public void send_click(View view) {
        socket.send(((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_test)).getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: have you given the permission in manifest.?

Comment: @Sreyas here is my permission details.,
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: which version of android are you using.?

Comment: @Sreyas Android Marshmallow

Comment: is your client running.? you are trying to write something right.? where is your listener.?

Comment: the server you are connecting to is https? because handshaking issue invoke when issue with certificate authentication ? Do your server use certificates ?

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan server does not use any certificates

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing methods but you also have to make connection with your server.
You are not connecting your socket

After this:

```
socket = new SocketIO("http://192.168.2.23:808");
```

add:

```
socket.connect()
```

Comment: do let me know if it works. For further queries also contact me. Dont forget to mark post as answer if it works for you buddy. Happy Coding :)

Comment: i have already done this, Sir please refer this line in question code, 
`socket.connect(new IOCallback() {`

Comment: This is call back method in which you tell what socket is supposed to do when it connects. But you have to make connection manually by adding socket.connect() after creating socket and defining methods.

Comment: So kindly refer to my provided solution.